# App Crashes when after Initiating IOS Map GPS navigation and returning to the app

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, gps, mapkit

I am trying to start the GPS navigation with the following codes but my app crashes and it doesn't tell me anything.  The map app and turn by turn navigation starts up fine and runs fine after it's initiated but my app crashes.

***UPDATED***

Sorry, let me add more context. After the navigation and GPS starts and I try to return to my app, the app crashes. Here is the full code.

```
 import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreData

class DetailViewController: UIViewController  {

    var pho : Pho? = nil

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var phoneLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var zomatoLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var googleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var yelpLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet var saveButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        // We need just to get the documents folder url
        let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

        //         now lets get the directory contents (including folders)

//        do {
//            let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
//            print(directoryContents)
//            
//            for x in directoryContents {
//                print(x)
//            }
//            
//        } catch let error as NSError {
//            print(error.localizedDescription)
//        }




    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.titleLabel.text = self.pho!.name
        self.phoneLabel.text = String(self.pho!.phoneNumber)
        self.addressLabel.text = self.pho!.address

        self.zomatoLabel.text = "\(self.pho!.rating) - \(self.pho!.votes) reviews"

        self.googleLabel.text = "\(self.pho!.gRating)"

        self.yelpLabel.text = "\(self.pho!.yRating) - \(self.pho!.yVotes) reviews"

        let latitudeAnn:CLLocationDegrees = self.pho!.latitude
        let longitudeAnn:CLLocationDegrees = self.pho!.longitude

        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeAnn, longitudeAnn)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = location

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Restaurant")
        //        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude = %@", latitude)
        let firstPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", "\(self.pho!.name)")
        let secondPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "address = %@", "\(self.pho!.address)")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [firstPredicate, secondPredicate])

        do {

            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

            if results.count > 0 {
                print(results)
                self.saveButton.hidden = true

                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {


                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }


    @IBAction func initDirection(sender: AnyObject) {



                let latitudeAnn:CLLocationDegrees = self.pho!.latitude
                let longitudeAnn:CLLocationDegrees = self.pho!.longitude

                let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeAnn, longitudeAnn)

                let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
                let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
                let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

                mapItem.name = "\(self.pho!.name)"

                mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)


    }

    @IBAction func savePho(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.saveButton.hidden = true

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let newRestaurant = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Restaurant", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        newRestaurant.setValue(self.pho!.latitude, forKey: "latitude")

        newRestaurant.setValue(self.pho!.longitude, forKey: "longitude")

        newRestaurant.setValue(self.pho!.name, forKey: "name")

        newRestaurant.setValue(self.pho!.phoneNumber, forKey: "phone")

        newRestaurant.setValue(self.pho!.address, forKey: "address")

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("There was a problem")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the details of the crash?

Comment: It doesn't say. That's what frustrates me.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the XML was corrupted. My codes were fine. I created another View Controller, added all the widgets and connected my codes and everything worked.